# clang-tidy displays errors in system headers

Tags: clang, clang-tidy, clang-static-analyzer

I'm trying to run **clang-tidy** on my IAR project, but I would like to ignore system header files. I tried the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638293/ignore-system-headers-in-clang-tidy) but they didn't work (read on for the results). Here's my project structure:

```
Proj
----Src
----Inc
SysHdrs
```

And this is my **clang-tidy** command from inside `Proj`:

```
clang-tidy.exe Src/*.c -header-filter=Proj\\Inc\\.* -checks=* -- -I"abs/path/to/Proj/Inc" -isystem"abs/path/to/SysHdrs"
```

I'm getting warnings on my Src files, as well as on some SysHdrs files such as `SysHdrs/DLib_Defaults.h` and `SysHdrs/yvals.h`. For example:

```
abs/path/to/SysHdrs/DLib_Defaults.h:563:6: error: "Compiler must support __weak" [clang-diagnostic-error]
    #error "Compiler must support __weak"
     ^
abs/path/to/SysHdrs/yvals.h:37:4: error: "DLib compiled with wrong (version of IAR) compiler" [clang-diagnostic-error]
  #error "DLib compiled with wrong (version of IAR) compiler"
   ^
abs/path/to/SysHdrs/yvals.h:232:11: error: unknown type name '__WCHAR_T_TYPE__' [clang-diagnostic-error]
  typedef __WCHAR_T_TYPE__ _Wchart;

abs/path/to/SysHdrs/yvals.h:358:3: error: expected identifier or '(' [clang-diagnostic-error]
  __WEAK __ATTRIBUTES void __iar_Locksyslock_Malloc(void);
  ^
```

Note that I do need to supply the system headers to clang, because otherwise it'd complain about a missing `stdio.h` / `string.h` etc.

As far as I know the `-header-filter` should filter out whatever doesn't match the regex pattern, so my system headers shouldn't be included in the outuput. Further, I've explicitly set the `SysHdrs` as "system headers" by using the `-isystem` identifier.

I even tried `-header-filter=main\.h` and it still processes the system headers.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: i used a little different syntax, maybe try: `-isystem abs/path/to/SysHdrs`; I used cmake and at the end i ended in CMakeLists.txt with `include_directories(SYSTEM ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/include)` because of his the gcc compiled this as system headers. i am not quite sure, but maybe cmake create all that is needed. Can't find it now

Comment: @Chris - Got it, thanks,

Comment: what was the solution or error? maybe also solve your own question with an answer

Comment: @Chris - I haven't solved it yet.